# javascript source code for colour palette generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, image

i am creating a website in asp.net and i am just wondering is any way to generate color palette from an image using JavaScript? Similar to

1) http://www.cssdrive.com/imagepalette/
2) http://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromanimage

Answer (score 0):

Thought I answered this earlier, but I think it was deleted. There is a jquery plugin that does something similar:

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/

Comment: Fareesh, thanks for your reply. i Want to generate color palette FROM IMAGE. But with xcolor.js i can get the colors of the current page. If i am wrong pls help me out here.

Comment: Sorry, your question looked similar to one I had answered before. I will look around and let you know. You can get a lot of Kuler's functionality from my link, but you will need to be able to pull out the color from an image as you were saying. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Fareesh Vijayarangam , i don't mind even it's mix of server side(.net) and client side.